# Winforms C# Error con ComboBox anidados con mscorlib.dll en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Ayuda con el error:

> 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll. Información adicional: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

Tengo un error cuando inicio por primera vez mi frame ya que tengo `ComboBox` anidados de Estado, Municipio y Localidad. Los últimos dos se actualizan con eventos. Municipio se actualiza cuando cambia algo en Estado, y Localidad se actualiza cuando hay un cambio en Municipio.

Mi problema ocurre cuando se llena por primera vez el `ComboBox` Estado, ya que me imagino que se activa por detrás el evento `cmbEstado_SelectedValueChanged`del `ComboBox` y por tanto hay un error en Municipio ya que no reconoce la propiedad `cmbEstado.ValueMember`, que debería ser el id de Estado. Pero solo es la primera vez. Ya que después de que carga ya no me da el error.

Este es el código del llenado de Estado

```
try
{
    List<Estado> estados = ctrl.llenarDataSource<Estado>().ToList();
    cmbEstado.DisplayMember = "stNombre";
    cmbEstado.ValueMember = "id";
    cmbEstado.DataSource = estados;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ctrl.msjError(ex.Message + " " + ex.Source);
}
```

Y este el de Municipio

```
try
{
    cmbMunicipio.DataSource = ctrl.consultarConID<Municipio>("idEstado", int.Parse(cmbEstado.SelectedValue.toString()));
    cmbMunicipio.DisplayMember = "stNombre";
    cmbMunicipio.ValueMember = "id";
}
catch (Exception)
{


}
```

Como verán mitigo el error con el Catch vacio para que no haga nada, sin embargo, considero que no es lo mejor hacer eso. ¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Has probado a comprobar que `SelectedValue` no sea `null`? `if (cmbEstado.SelectedValue!=null) { cmbMunicipio.DataSource = ctrl.consultarConID<Municipio>("idEstado", int.Parse(cmbEstado.SelectedValue.toString()));...`?

Comment: Si intente pero no lo corrigio. Es que como tal en la primera ejecución del programa se manda el SelectedValue como String por ejemplo se manda Aguascalientes en vez de 1 y como tal no va nulo. Lo que hice fue comparar que el SelectedValue fuera de tipo int 32 y asi ya no causaba ninguna excepción. Gracias por tu ayuda amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba validando lo siguiente:

1. Cuando el `SelectedIndex` del Combo sea diferente de Null
2. Cuando el SelectedIndex del Combo sea > -1
3. Cuando el `SelectedItem` del Combo sea diferente de Null

> En ves de usuar el Evento `cmbEstado_SelectedValueChanged` prueba usando `cmbEstado_SelectionChangeCommitted` [Evento: SelectionChangeCommitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) . Se produce cuando el usuario cambia el elemento seleccionado y se muestra dicho cambio en ComboBox.

Comment: Muchas gracias.